# What is the type of e.values and e.oldValues, when reading boolean values?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox, triggers, eventtrigger

Type of `e.values` differs markedly. Do we know the exact type that is returned in the event object of triggers for Boolean types?

Comment: Please don't add answer in question. Remove it and add it as a answer below.

Comment: If you add a answer below, I can edit it to provide reps.

Comment: I think you got it.  So what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the cell by his coordinates , it return the correct values as you can see in this other table. Values of direct reading of cells

[image: Table of values & type of values]
I got this values by  clicking on checkboxes and triggering onEdit function. the values read are not boolean.
in the table, you can see that the values read are TRUE/FALSE and string type.
Reading the cell by his coordinates , it return the correct values as you can see in this other table.   [image: Values of direct reading of cells]

you can test with this code

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var eA1 = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  // e.value and his typeof
  ui.alert("(" + eA1 + ") e.value=" + e.value);
  ui.alert("(" + eA1 + ") typeof e.value=" + typeof e.value);

  // eValue and his typeof
  var eValue=e.value;
  ui.alert("reading of  eValue......");
  ui.alert("(" + eA1 + ") eValue=" + eValue);
  ui.alert("(" + eA1 + ") typeof eValue=" + typeof eValue);

  // getting de value of (e)cell
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var eTargetCell = sheet.getRange(eA1);
  var eCellValue = eTargetCell.getValue();

  // eCellValue and his typeof
  ui.alert("direct reading of cell.......");
  ui.alert("(" + eA1 + ") eValue=" + eCellValue);
  ui.alert("(" + eA1 + ") typeof eValue=" + typeof eCellValue);
}
```

You can easily make a function to get the boolean value of 'e' cell. To get the correct value of e.oldValue... you can recover it in the original cell, if needed, easily by

```
e.range.setValue(eOldValue);
```

or in another cell(not tested this point)

Comment: Thanks for contributing to the community. I added the pictures in your original post. Feel free to edit as needed.

Comment: @TheMaster, thanks for your help. I will try to do better next time.